# "First post" review test failed and got suspended

Tags: discussion, first-post-review

I was reviewing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11691242) post and I thought it would be good to edit it. But when I clicked on 'edit', it said that the post is removed and cannot be edited or deleted.

Since the post is deleted already, there is no point in flagging it. So I clicked "No action needed" because the post is already taken care of. And now I got banned because of bad reviewing. Is it my mistake or something wrong from SO?

Comment: I'm actually pretty sure this is a long-standing bug related to suggested edits and review audits, but reproducing it consistently has been something of a problem.